# Split column into multiple columns by criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, pivot

I have a query like the following:

```
select
  table.date,
  table.shift,
  sum(table.value)
from
  db.table
where
  table.date >= date '2020-01-01' and
  table.filter = 'type'
group by
  table.date,
  table.shift
order by
  table.date,
  table.shift;
```

That returns data this way:

```
date       | shift | sum(value)
-----------|-------|------------
2020-01-06 | 1     | 15
2020-01-06 | 3     | 12
2020-01-07 | 1     | 20
2020-01-07 | 2     | 38
2020-01-09 | 1     |  6
2020-01-09 | 2     | 22
2020-01-09 | 3     | 14
2020-01-10 | 1     | 17
2020-01-10 | 2     |  3
2020-01-10 | 3     | 10
```

I'm trying to get it like this but I don't know how:

```
date       | 1  | 2  | 3
-----------|----|----|----
2020-01-06 | 15 |    | 12
2020-01-07 | 20 | 38 |
2020-01-09 |  6 | 22 | 14
2020-01-10 | 17 |  3 | 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an addition subquery or CTE. You can pivot your dataset using conditional aggregation with slight modifications of your query: just remove `shift` from the `group by` clause, and then implement conditional logic in the `sum()`s:

```
select
  date,
  sum(case when shift = 1 then value end) shift1,
  sum(case when shift = 2 then value end) shift2,
  sum(case when shift = 3 then value end) shift3
from
  db.table
where
  date >= date '2020-01-01'
  and filter = 'type'
group by date
order by date
```

Note:

- there is no need to prefix the column names since a single table comes into play. I removed those
- `date` is the name of datatype in Oracle, hence not a good choice for a column name

Comment: This answer is the one that better fits my needs so I'll accept it. Wasn't expecting this much of a [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731), more like close as duplicate of some question I didn't found or maybe a "have you searched?" sort of accusation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select t.date,
       sum(case when t.shift = 1 then t.value else 0 end),
       sum(case when t.shift = 2 then t.value else 0 end),
       sum(case when t.shift = 3 then t.value else 0 end)
from db.table as t
where t.date >= date '2020-01-01' and
      t.filter = 'type'
group by t.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
with cte as
(
select
  table.date,
  table.shift,
  sum(table.value) as val
from
  db.table
where
  table.date >= date '2020-01-01' and
  table.filter = 'type'
group by
  table.date,
  table.shift
order by
  table.date,
  table.shift
)
select date, max(case when shift=1 then val end) as 1,
max(case when shift=1 then val end) as 2,
max(case when shift=1 then val end) as 3
from cte
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` for this as follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ( SELECT
  table.date,
  table.shift,
  table.value
from
  db.table
where
  table.date >= date '2020-01-01' and
  table.FILTER = 'type' ) 
  PIVOT 
  ( SUM ( VALUE ) FOR SHIFT IN ( 1,2,3 ))
ORDER BY date;
```

Cheers!!